# How do you accept and reduce arguments depending on another argument

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take more arguments depending on the data type of another argument.

```py
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, img, img_size, animation)
         ???
```

If I give the class an `img`, I want the class to accept `img_size` as another parameter but I also want it to not accept `animaton` as an parameter. But if I give it `animation`, I want the class to not need to accept `img` and `img_size` as parameters.

The difference between `img` and `animation` is that `img` should be an object from an `Image` class, and `animation` should be a dictionary. So how would I vary the amount of arguments that I accept depending on what they are?

Comment: If you have them as keyword arguments, you can use as few or as many as you need for a given case. Then the init  method just needs to do error handling for when incompatible keywords are set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can give you some ideas:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, img=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if img is not None:
            if 'animaton' in kwargs:
                raise Exception('animation is not allowed')
            self.img_size = kwargs['img_size']
        elif 'animation' in kwargs:
            if 'img' in kwargs or 'img_size' in kwargs:
                raise Exception('img and img_size is not allowed with animation param')


e = Enemy(animation='some', img_size='ada')
```